# How do you generate resources for inclusion in src/main/resources without that triggering a subsequent build in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I'm trying to achieve the following in Eclipse:

When a source file changes, run an custom class that's included as part of the project dependencies, this class generates a file which needs to be placed into src/main/resources (such that it will get checked into source control by any developer working on the project).  I'd even settle for /generated rather than src/main/resources.

I have the following, which seems to do the right thing, however even though the generated file is being placed into /generated, it triggers a further eclipse build, so essentially a circular loop of builds.

The following triggers m2e into action:

```
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>java</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute>
                                        <runOnConfiguration>false</runOnConfiguration>
                                        <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
                                    </execute>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

The following triggers the custom class:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>SchemaGenerator</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>jit.SchemaGenerator</mainClass>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>${project.basedir}/generated</argument>
                            <argument>schema.xml</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: Generated "things" are usually place under `${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/[TASK]`, then configure whatever process you need with this. I guess Eclipse will not trigger a build if you generate something inside `target`.

Comment: That's correct, anything under target doesn't kick off a build.  However I'd like the file placed within the project so that it can be put into source control. I have everything under target being excluded from source control.

Comment: If it is generated, it shouldn't be under SCM IMHO. And seeing it the other way, if it is under SCM, it shouldn't be generated.

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate that and I do agree.  This is a bit of a 'special' case.

Comment: After some further thought and rework of an internal process, I'm going to avoid the need to check in the generated file.